# how to multiply two columns which include dash(-)?

Tags: pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                  'A': [15, '-', 173, 190, 68],
                  'B': ['-', 254, '-', 16, 76],
                  'C': [12, '-', 110, 35, 98],
                  'D': [125, 89, 308, 211, 174],
                  'E': [19, 21, '-', 162, '-']
                  })
```

I have two columns that I want multiply each other but these columns include "-". Before convert the dash to float or replacing with 0, I can make multiplication but I dont want too many dash. Also, when I export my data to excel, my data convert to string because of these dashes. I want all of them as integer or float but include dashes. Is it possible? How can I multiply these columns without removing dash(-)?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is best - replace `-` by something numeric, e.g. by `NaN`, because for multiple is necessary all numeric values:

```
df = df.mask(df.values == '-').astype(float)
```

Or:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

---

```
print (df)
       A      B      C      D      E
0   15.0    NaN   12.0  125.0   19.0
1    NaN  254.0    NaN   89.0   21.0
2  173.0    NaN  110.0  308.0    NaN
3  190.0   16.0   35.0  211.0  162.0
4   68.0   76.0   98.0  174.0    NaN
```

Last if need `-` back:

```
df = df.fillna('-')
```

Or convert missing values by parameter `na_rep` in [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel(file, na_rep='-')
```

---

But it is possible with try-expect in function, but really slow, so not recommended:

```
def mult_with_dash(x):
    try:
        return float(x['A']) * float(x['E']) 
    except Exception:
        return '-'

df['new'] = df.apply(mult_with_dash, axis=1)
print (df)
     A    B    C    D    E    new
0   15    -   12  125   19    285
1    -  254    -   89   21      -
2  173    -  110  308    -      -
3  190   16   35  211  162  30780
4   68   76   98  174    -      -
```